# Compilation of rosjava fails

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to compile rosjava and did: roscd rosjava; rosmake. And got the following error message:

```
compile:
  [javac] Compiling 80 source files to /home/tompe/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/target/classes
  [javac] /home/tompe/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/old_style/MessageSerializationFactory.java:38: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds MessageType,java.lang.Object
  [javac]     MessageType message = messageFactory.newMessage(messageType);
  [javac]                                                    ^
  [javac] /home/tompe/ros/rosjava_core/rosjava/src/main/java/org/ros/internal/message/old_style/MessageSerializationFactory.java:52: type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds MessageType,java.lang.Object
```

Any ideas? Are using jdk1.6.0_17.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11779/compilation-of-rosjava-fails./) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Updating to jdk1.6.0_29 solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1